# how to compare two different length objects in for loop?

Tags: javascript, object

I have tried to create a login function which when the user enters the vaild name and password then it will print "welcome user " else "invalid user".

In my code it accepts one username and password and showing invalid for another one...I cant understand why its showing like this...

code:

```
<script>
     let userName=document.getElementById("input1");
     let mailId=document.getElementById("input2");
     var out=[{Name:"dhanam",mail:"dhanamram98@gmail.com"}, 
              {Name:"alamelu",mail:"alamu98@gmail.com"}];
     function input()
     {
         var input=userName.value;
         var output=mailId.value;
         var created=[{Name:input,mail:output}];
         return created
     }
     function output()
     {

          var inp=input();

         for(var i=0;i<inp.length;i++)
         {
             for(var j=0;j<out.length;j++)
             {
                  console.log(inp[i].Name+inp[i].mail);
                  console.log(out[j].Name+out[j].mail);
              if((inp[i].Name== out[j].Name)&& 
                  (inp[i].mail==out[j].mail))
               {
              document.getElementById("out1").innerText="welcome
                                                         user";

                }
             else{
               document.getElementById("out1").innerText="Invalid 
                                                          user";
                }
             }

           }

       }
      var but=document.getElementById("out");
      but.addEventListener("click",output);
  </script>
```

find fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xp1Lrbdh/#&togetherjs=d0wTznLFgu

Comment: Please fix the indentation. It's hard to follow the flow in your code. And adding some spaces would also help.

Comment: because you can only show invalid after you go through them all. You really should use `find()` instead of a for loop. And as always, I hope this is just for practice since it is not secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The issue is because of the iteration you are doing even after finding if entered user is valid user. In simple terms, putting a break statement solves your problem.
See the snippet below:

    let userName=document.getElementById("input1");
    let mailId=document.getElementById("input2");
    var out=[{Name:"dhanam",mail:"dhanamram98@gmail.com"}, 
    {Name:"alamelu",mail:"alamu98@gmail.com"}];
    function input()
    {
        var input=userName.value;
        var output=mailId.value;
        var created=[{Name:input,mail:output}];
        return created
    }
    function output()
    {
        var inp=input();
        for(var i=0;i<inp.length;i++)
        {
            for(var j=0;j<out.length;j++)
            {
                console.log(inp[i].Name, inp[i].mail);
                console.log(out[j].Name, out[j].mail);
                if((inp[i].Name== out[j].Name)&&(inp[i].mail==out[j].mail))
                {
                    document.getElementById("out1").innerText="welcome user";
                    break;

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("out1").innerText="Invalid user";
    }


    }

  }

  }
  var but=document.getElementById("out");
  but.addEventListener("click",output);
```

**NOTE:** This is not a best practice to verify credentials also avoid using var, use let, const instead

Answer (score 1):

```
const accounts = [
  {
    name:"dhanam",
    mail:"dhanamram98@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    name:"alamelu",
    mail:"alamu98@gmail.com"
  }
]

function output() {
   const nameNode = document.getElementById("input1")
     const mailNode = document.getElementById("input2")
     const name = nameNode.value
   const mail = mailNode.value
   const found = accounts.find(a => a.name === name && a.mail === mail)
   if (found) {
            document.getElementById("out1").innerText="welcome user";
     } else {
            document.getElementById("out1").innerText="Invalid user";
     }  
}

var but=document.getElementById("out");
but.addEventListener("click",output);
```